# Visual Studio 2010 and protobuf-csharp-port

Tags: visual-studio-2010, protocol-buffers, custom-build-step

We're using Jon Skeet's proto-csharp-port, and I'm running into some difficulties when mixing it with ReSharper in Visual Studio 2010.

We generate the .cs files via a custom MSBuild target, hooked up as follows:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="CompileProtos" />
```

The `CompileProtos` target runs `ProtoGen` and then adds the generated .cs files to the `@(Compile)` item group, by using `CreateItem`. This looks in a defined directory and compiles every .proto file it finds, so they're not listed in the project.

Where it falls down is that ReSharper doesn't recognise the content of the .cs files (because they're not in the project and might not exist yet), so I can't get the solution analysis light to go green.

If I add the .cs files to the project, then I get a build failure, because the .cs file has been added to the `Compile` item group twice.

I know that Marc's protobuf-net has Visual Studio 2008 [goodness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453820/protocol-buffers-in-c-projects-using-protobuf-net-best-practices-for-code-gene) in it, and I'm looking for something similar, but for Jon's protobuf-csharp-port and for Visual Studio 2010.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to add the .proto files to the project, have them built correctly, and have Visual Studio and ReSharper know about the generated .cs files, so that IntelliSense and solution analysis work properly.

I'm guessing that something like how .xsd files can implicitly generate .cs files would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by removing the `CreateItem` from the `CompileProtos` target, and by defining it as a proper `ItemGroup`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protocols Include="$(ProtocolsPath)\*.proto"/>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="@(Protocols -> '%(Filename).cs')"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

This means that Visual Studio (and ReSharper) pick up the .cs files correctly, once they've been built, and ReSharper's full solution analysis stops complaining.

Unfortunately, Visual Studio has a habit of expanding the `ItemGroup` into individual `Compile` entries, but I can check for that before checking anything in.

Comment: Can you share the complete target set, please?

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to get this working by implementing a [custom tool](http://www.christophercrooker.com/visual-studio-2010-rc-custom-tool-for-code-generation-and-jquery14-with-intellisense-for-scriptsharp) for [code generation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/xsd2class.aspx), but I've run into a seemingly insurmountable hurdle:

`protoc` takes a directory full of `.proto` files and generates a `.protobin` file. This is then fed to `ProtoGen` which spits out a .cs file for each protocol definition. Unfortunately, it appears that the `.protobin` file needs to contain all of the definitions, otherwise you get **Error: Unable to resolve all dependencies**.

Since the custom tool model in Visual Studio assumes a single input file and a single output file (i.e. foo.proto -> foo.cs), it doesn't look like this can be made to work.

At least, not without finding some way to include all of `foo.proto`'s imported `.proto` files in `foo.protobin`, anyway.