# C#, Protobuf file, NuGet-package

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, csproj

I have a nuget package that has 'proto' files in the "lib/protos" path.
How can I specify the path to these files in a project that uses the NuGet package?
I don't know what to add to csproj. How to replace commas?

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="My.Custom.NugetPack" />
   <Protobuf Include="$(???)/lib/protos/*.proto" ProtoRoot="$(???)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And the second question. How to specify a link from a *.proto file? File from current project should refer to file from nuget.

Comment: What does `has 'proto' files in the "lib/protos"` mean? Are the files included as content in the NuGet package? If so, where do they appear in the target project? That's the path you need to pass to the `Protobuf` element.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638832/3225